# The cast to value type 'Int32' failed null value LINQ

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq

I am trying to add some values together using a view and LINQ this is my code below

```
var getProducts = from p in Entity.Products
                  join od in getOrderDetails on p.id equals od.productId into proDetails
                  orderby proDetails.Sum(q => q.quantity) descending
                  select new Common.Views.ProductQuantitySold()
                  {
                      productId = p.id,
                      productName = p.name,
                      productDesc = p.description,
                      qtySold = proDetails.Sum(q => q.quantity)
                  };
return getProducts.Take(10).AsQueryable();
```

In the line `qtySold = proDetails.Sum(q => q.quantity)` I am getting the cast value error. I know it is something about the null or zero but how should I implement it?

Comment: Show your `ProductQuantitySold` class definition and class which defines `quantity`. Have you compile-time or runtime error?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try replace the following line:

```
qtySold = proDetails.Sum(q => q.quantity)
```

to

```
qtySold = proDetails.Sum(q => (int?)q.quantity) ?? 0
```

Answer (score 1):

I assume it's a compilation error. If it's not, please leave a comment. Try to cast the result of your sum to an `int` or to cast every element of `proDetails` to an `int`.

Examples:

```
qtySold = (int) proDetails.Sum(q => q.quantity)
```

Alternatively:

```
qtySold = proDetails.Cast<int>().Sum(q => q.quantity)
```

Please let me know if it works.

Answer (score 1):

```
qtySold = proDetails.Sum(q => (Int32?)q.quantity) ?? 0
```